# Constructing a 2D vector from a mysql query using Qt

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, vector

I have a query statement that selects a list of tools. These tools need to be placed into a 2D vector, where the first level is it's category and second is the category's "bucket".

```
struct Tool {};
typedef boost::shared_ptr< Tool > ToolPtr;
typedef std::vector< ToolPtr > ToolVec;
typedef std::vector< ToolVec > ToolCategory;
```

The query statement looks like this:

```
const QString getTools =
"SELECT tool_id, category_id, category_name, tool_name FROM tool_relation "
"WHERE course_id = ? ORDER BY category_id ASC, tool_id ASC";

q.bindValue(0, courseID);
q.exec();

while (q.next())
{

}
```

I would like to do this with one query statement, but the only way I can think of is to use a temporary pointer to the correct bucket and test every record to see if the category id changes. Seems inefficient.

EDIT: Something like this is what I came up with when only using one query statement.

```
ToolVector *curBucket = 0;

int curCategory = 0;

while (q.next())
{
    if (q.value(1).toInt() != curCategory)
    {
        curCategory = q.value(1).toInt();

        ToolVec toolVec;

        curBucket = &toolVec;

        categories.push_back(toolVec);
    }

    ToolPtr toolPtr(new Tool(
                        q.value(0).toInt(),
                        q.value(2).toString()));

    curBucket->push_back(toolPtr);
}
```

Comment: What inefficiency do you see?

Comment: @PavelZdenek See my edit. Its the if statement in the loop. I decided that its probably better to create the buckets first using SELECT DISTINCT on the category_id and then do another query to actually grab all the tools. As long as both queries order the results by category_id, they fall into the correct buckets.

Answer (score 1):

We probably differ in the definition of "efficiency". For me it's speed and memory requirements. Processing two SELECT statements will be always slower and more consuming than processing one, even with `if` statement for each returned row.

But, even that i don't know anything about your logic, i am somewhat missing how you would be looking for the tool buckets. `category_id` is not saved anywhere, and `category_name` only inside the `Tool` struct. You cannot find a bucket unless you iterate all tools. What about a bucket `map` ? It might also fulfill your efficiency requirements:

```
typedef std::map< int, ToolVec > ToolCategory;

while (q.next())
{
  curCategory = q.value(1).toInt();
  ...      
  categories[curCategory].push_back(toolPtr);
}
```